# Error to build project in VS2010:"could not load file or assemby..."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker-errors, visual-build-professional

I just install VS2010 and try to build a project. The below Error was shown,

"Error while trying run project: could not load file or assembly 'PROJECT' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly mainfest"

I reinstall VS2010 but the problem is remained. would u please help me?!?

Comment: Obviously the problem is in your project. Try to delete PROJECT from references and add it again.

Comment: I Create another simple project, and the problem is in there too!!

Comment: You could give me your project sources. Just zip the solution and send to me somehow. I will try to compile it on my PC.

Comment: many thanks, it is compiled in another computer, but in my computer this problem is shown...;(

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling crystal report for visualstudio 2010

http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_1.zip

and also add following in you appconfig